# Display images in angular 2 project from AWS s3 Bucket

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I am creating an Angular 2 portfolio project.

I have a folder with several images in my aws s3 bucket.

How can I display all the photos inside the folder in the page.

I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

The images in your S3 bucket all have a public URL assigned by Amazon.  In order to enable access to the images via this URL you need to configure access to the bucket and the items in it.  See the [AWS S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html) for more information.  At a high level, if you look at the bucket/item properties in the console you can manage permissions - by granting everyone open/download permissions S3 will serve the images through the URL, which is displayed for each item in the properties tab of the console.

Once you have this URL set the src attributes of your html accordingly and the images will display.

As with all things AWS there are more and less sophisticated ways of managing this - the above example is straightforward for getting started but may not give you all the control you want.  Again, the AWS docs are probably your best bet there unless you have a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you, Ironmanwaring, I can get all the images with a for loop with a regular javascript function but I can't make it work in an angular component or service.

Comment: So you're trying to list out the file names instead of (or in addition to) the images themselves?  If you share the code of what's working in regular javascript and what isn't working in your angular code that will help troubleshoot.

Comment: No, just the photos, any images folders are considered objects. Angular2 *ngfor does not work with objects, just arrays. So, I tried the service , pipe, observable and I cannot make it work. I can make it work with a for loop in regular javascript, but since I am working in angular2, I wanted to use its methods. Thanks for your response.

Comment: hard to help troubleshoot without seeing the code, sorry

Comment: whenever posting any question kindly show a snippet of your code